# Improving the SEO of my website

Tags: seo, google-search

I have recently uploaded a website for basic web designing tutorials with proper examples and demos. I wanna improve it, such that it comes in google results. ? can anyone please suggest me what to do for the same.I have already used meta tags in my website

http://sillythingsthatmatter.in/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now yet, but I was told not to use dirty trick in SEO (like white text on white background etc.), since once google discovers it, you'll get a big penalty, a lot of negative points!

Comment: Then u should not have replied to the question

Comment: I replied because I found this information very useful for anyone beginning with SEO - do not cheat.